# Transpose jagged 2d list to 1d list

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, jagged-arrays

I am implementing ZoomableCanvas http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx

It's a WPF control that allows for virtualized display of objects in a canvas. To take advantage of the virtualization, the library requires you to implement a method called 'Query' on your datasource object. The Query method lazily returns IEnumerable<int> given a Rect, where the int represents the position in the datasource of the element and the Rect is the visible area of the canvas (items not visible in the canvas are not returned and therefore not drawn). My data source is sorted such that the X and Y values are sorted (myList[0] would contain the smallest X,Y coordinates )

Given this info, I can simply do the following to get my items

```
int c = this.Count;

for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
{
    if (rectangle.Contains(new Point(this[j].left, this[j].top)))
    {
       yield return (int)j;
    }
}
```

However, we're traversing the entire list and there's 100k+ items in the list. This performs remarkably badly, especially when viewing the bottom-right of the canvas as those items are at the end of the list.

So I tried transposing the data so that I can take the points in my visible area on the canvas and know exactly what indexes correspond in the array.

```
        var tilewidth = MapWidthInTiles;

        for (var x = Math.Max(left, 0); x <= right; x++)
        {
            for (var y = Math.Max(top, 0); y <= bottom; y++)
            {

                var i = (y * tilewidth) + x;

                if (i < Count)
                {
                    yield return (int)i;
                }
            }
        }
```

This works except my dataset is irregular (I'm drawing a map), as the map may have missing or incomplete 'tiles'. Hence my array essentially is jagged. [image: Illustration of the jagged dataset missing 'tiles']

Basically, I'm looking for a way where I can quickly identify elements given a 2D geometry  in a 1D array, where the elements in the 2D array may not be complete or contiguous. Normally the [y * widthOfAllItems] + x would give me the proper 2d -> 1d transposition. But because of the missing elements, the equation is off. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need not to STORE your items in a 1D Array, you need to RETURN them to the ZoomableCanvas in a 1D Array. So feel free to store them in the most efficient way you can think of.
QuadTree might be one solution to store your points : a tree where each node has 4 children NE, SE, SW, NW, (NE=North-East, ...) each one is either empty, filled with one color, or has 4 children also.
Another solution : Working with the islands as base objects, using the bounding box to go faster.... and maybe store the islands in a tree.